# OpenMP paralelization inhibits vectorization

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization

I am new to OpenMP and I am trying to paralelize following code using OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
{
   for(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
   {
       outX[k+j*m] = inB2[j+n * k] / inA2[j*n + j];

       for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
       {
           inB2[k*n+i] -= inA2[i+n * j] * outX[k + m*j];
       }
   }
}
```

Paralelize the outer cycle is pretty straight-forward, but to optimize it, I wanted to paralelize the inner-most cycle (the one iterating over i) as well. But when I try to do that like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    inB2[k*n+i] -= inA2[i+n * j] * outX[k + m*j];
}
```

the compiler does not vectorize the inner cycle ("loop versioned for vectorization because of possible aliasing"), which makes it run slower. I compiled it using `gcc -ffast-math -std=c++11 -fopenmp -O3 -msse2 -funroll-loops -g -fopt-info-vec prog.cpp`

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: I am using __restrict keyword for the arrays.

EDIT2: Interesting is, that when I keep only the pragma in the inner cycle and remove it from the outer, gcc will vectorize it. So the problem only happens, when I try to paralelize both cycles.

EDIT3: The compiler will vectorize the loop when I use #pragma omp parallel for simd. But it's still slower than without parallelizing the inner loop at all.

Comment: It's easier to vectorize manually, than parallelize. Why not to just do it? (and keep automatic parallelization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers. I managed to vectorize the inner loop using `#pragma omp parallel for simd`, but the program was slower than without parallelizing. I eventually found a slightly different algorithm to solve the problem, which is much faster.
Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: The "VIPO" (Vectorize Inner, Parallel Outer) usually is best. So pure SIMD on the inner loop (No 'parallel for') , and then whether or not parallelizing the outer loop helps is usually a test-it-n-see endevour. On bandwidth limited situations sometimes prefetch helps, but cache misses can have a lot of cores doing little real-work, whereas a single core can stream data through unimpeded. It is rarely easy guess right.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that after you parallelized the inner loop, your compiler lost the track of `inA2`, `inB2` and `outX`. By default, it assumes that any regions of memory pointed by any pointers may overlap with each other. In C language the C99 Standard introduced `restrict` keyword, which informs the compiler that a pointer points to a memory block which is not pointed by any other pointer. C++ haven't got such a keyword, but, fortunately, `g++` has an appropriate extension. So try to add `__restrict` to declarations of the pointers touched by the loop. For example, replace

```
double* outX;
```

with

```
double* __restrict outX;
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the case. I am using __restrict. Good point though, I will add it to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the inner loop vecotorzed first? and then adding the parallel part (which might result in slower performance depending on cache misses)

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
{
   for(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
   {
       outX[k+j*m] = inB2[j+n * k] / inA2[j*n + j];
Q1 = k*n
Q2 = n*j
Q3 = m*j + k
#pragma omp declare simd private(i,j,k,m,Q1,Q2,Q3) linear(i) uniform(outX,inA2,inB2) shared(inB2,inA2,outX)
       for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
       {
           inB2[Q1+i] -= inA2[Q2+i] * outX[Q3];
       }
   }
}
```

It always take me some time getting the #pragma right with the shared, public etc... And I did not test this.

Comment: Thanks for idea. As I mentioned in EDIT3, I mad le it vectorize using simply #pragma omp parallel for simd. But it's still slower than without paralelizing the inner loop at all.

Comment: That might indicate that it is bandwidth limited rather than computationally limited.